# Kotlin append to file

Tags: kotlin, io, append

I absolutely new to Kotlin and seems I just can not get the append-to-file procedure. 
I have filename given by val path: String = ".....txt"
I want a method in my class that takes line: String and appends it at the end of my file (on new line). 
My test case is: two consequtive calls to method with two different lines for example "foo" and "bar" and I expect file like:

```
foo
bar
```

It works if my method looks like this:

```
fun writeLine(line: String) {
    val f = File(path!!)
    f.appendText(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"))
}
```

And it absolutely doesn`t work in any way like this:

```
    fun writeLine(line: String) {
        val f = File(path!!)
        f.bufferedWriter().use { out->
        out.append(line)
        out.newLine()
        }
    }
```

It rewrites my file with each call so I get only "bar" in my file.
It doesn`t work with printWriter either:

```
    fun writeLine(line: String) {
        val f = File(path!!)
        f.printWriter().use { out->
        out.append(line)
        }
    }
```

I`ve got the same result as for BufferedWriter. Why? I just can not get it. How do I append with BufferedWriter or PrintWriter?

Comment: Not directly a solution, but I highly recommend you avoid `File` if you can. See http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks

Comment: Thanks! I`ll look into it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Both `File.bufferedWriter` and `File.printWriter` actually rewrite the target file, replacing its content with what you write with them. This is mostly equivalent to what would happen if you used `f.writeText(...)`, not `f.appendText(...)`.

One solution would be to create a `FileOutputStream` in the append mode by using the appropriate constructor [`FileOutputStream(file: File, append: Boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)), for example:

```
FileOutputStream(f, true).bufferedWriter().use { writer ->
    //... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it. Unfortunately my reputation here is too low and I`m not allowed to make +1 to your answer, but it indeed clears things for me.

Comment: @user3575511 Your reputation is higher now :)

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I ended up using the following based on a combination of suggestions including the one from "hotkey". I needed for the append to be conditional including a newline to prepare for any future contents.

```
FileOutputStream(File(fileNameAndPath), isAppendMode).bufferedWriter().use { 
  writer -> writer.write(textToWrite) 
  if (isAppendMode) { writer.newLine() } 
}
```