# Android Automator: Is it possible to append file in Download folder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file, android-uiautomator

I've read the [Kotlin append to file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53383842/737172) thread, and my UIAutomator code looks like:

```kotlin
fun appendLog(text: String?) {
    val logFile = File("/sdcard/Download/autotest.log")
    if (!logFile.exists()) {
        try {
            logFile.createNewFile()
            Log.d(TAG, "Create new file $logFile Succeed!")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Create new file $logFile FAILED!, $e")
        }
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream(logFile, true).bufferedWriter().use { writer ->
            writer.append(text)
            writer.newLine()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Appending file $logFile FAILED!, $e")
    }
}

// test cas 1
appendLog("Some test result")

// test cas 2
appendLog("Other test results")
```

But got error from `adb logcat`

```sh
03-14 20:16:57.829 27499 27522 D LogTest : Create new file /sdcard/Download/autotest.log Succeed!
03-14 20:16:57.830 27499 27522 E LogTest : Appending file /sdcard/Download/autotest.log FAILED!, java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Download/autotest.log: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)

03-14 20:17:02.214 27499 27522 D LogTest : Create new file /sdcard/Download/autotest.log Succeed!
03-14 20:17:02.216 27499 27522 E LogTest : Appending file /sdcard/Download/autotest.log FAILED!, java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Download/autotest.log: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)
```

Comment: What should your code do?

Comment: Is it normal that you let execution of your code continue when there is a catch? Instead of stop?

Comment: Why posting twice the same log?

Comment: @blackapps Basically there're several auto test case trigger this `appendLog` function.

Comment: @blackapps I think I know what might be going on. I was trying to append the log in UIAutomator. Not the app itself.